# Progressive Web App not working properly on iOS

Tags: ios, tomcat, ssl-certificate, progressive-web-apps, tomcat9

This is the second time we are facing this issue. We have a PWA application, deployed through Tomcat. When accessing the starting URL for it on android and windows devices, you are greeted by the login screen, and in case it's your first time accessing it, you also receive the prompt to install it as a PWA. On iOS however, whenever you access the starting URL for it, you are greeted by the following screen:[How it looks on iOS device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVWdX.png). As you can see, the screen loads incorrectly, none of the css and html of it seems to arrive properly, and all you see is a distorted version of what would probably have been the iOS prompt that teaches you how to add the app to your home screen. The last time we had it, the issue was solved by making changes on the server.xml file for tomcat, and that seems to hold true because when this exact same application is deployed on that server (our homologation server), it works perfectly fine on both android and iOS. But we don't really understand what's the difference between the server.xml files on both servers, even after comparing them side-by-side. My best guess is that this is some apple security stuff blocking css, html and JS files from being loaded by the client. Has anyone ever faced this issue when deploying an application through tomcat? I would love to hear suggestions about what could be the issue, and I'm prepared to follow up with more information as requested. Thank you for your time.

We tried modifying the server.xml file for tomcat on the server where the issue is happening (client's server), making it match the one in our own server where everything works fine, but that doesn't appear to have fixed the issue. Again, the idea is that there might be something wrong with how apple devices are understanding the security certificate and in turn blocking the page from being fully loaded.